# MAX AND MIN IN RANDOM NUMBER

Tags: c

I need to write a C program to :
1. fills a 20 elementary array(marks) with random numbers between 0 and 100
2. print the number out 8 to a line.
3. Prints out the max and min and the average of the numbers.

I wrote following program and every thing is ok except min, I dont know how could I do it any help or tips would be really appreciates.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int random = 0;
    int num[20] = { 0 };
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (x = 0; x<20; x++)
    {
        random = rand() % 100 + 1;
        num[x] = random;

        if (num[x]>max)
        {
            max = num[x];
        }
        if (x % 8 == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        sum += random;
        printf("%d\t", num[x]);
    }

    avg = sum / 20;
    printf("\n\nthis is Max number: %d", max);
    printf("\nThis is average number:%d", avg);
    printf("\nThis is min number:", min);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Uh ... you did *see* that the code you've posted looks broken, right? With tons of "`enter code here`" prompts?

Comment: Could you please post it without the `enter code here` prefix all over the place???

Comment: Try pasting your code again. Something went horribly wrong here.

Comment: `enter code here` please reformat.

Comment: "Every thing is ok except `min`" - You have a condition `if(num[x]>max)` but you don't have the equivalent condition for `min`, what on earth did you expect??? The fact that you haven't noticed such an obvious answer to your question gives the impression that it's not you who wrote this code to begin with.

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: `stdlib.h` defines a constant called `RAND_MAX` which is a good starting point for the `min` variable.

Comment: Are you afraid of spaces, ordering and indentation but attractive to newlines and tabs?

Comment: You find the max value successfully.  Why *exactly* are you having problems finding the min value?  It is *exactly* the same, except looking for a smaller number instead of a bigger number.

Comment: `random = rand() % 100 + 1;` --> `random = rand() % 101;`, `printf("\nThis is min number:", min);` --> `printf("\nThis is min number:%d", min);`, `int min = 0;` --> `int min = 100;`

Answer (score 1):

You have a condition in your code which determines the maximum value. You need a same for finding the minimum value too,i.e,Something like this:

```
if (num[x]<min)
{
    min = num[x];
}
```

But this will never be true as `min` is 0 and `num[x]` will always be greater than 0. So set `min` to 100 by changing

```
int min = 0;
```

To

```
int min = 100;
```

But still,your code won't work as expected. This is because you forgot to add a format specifier(`%d`) in your last `printf`. So change

```
printf("\nThis is min number:", min);
```

To

```
printf("\nThis is min number:%d", min);
```

And finally,your code will work!

Comment: Just some thoughts: 1) Classic idiom is to initialize with `int min = INT_MAX; int max = INT_MIN`;  2) `avg = sum / 20;` could be `double avg = sum / 20.0;` or done with round-to-nearest `int` with `avg = (sum + 10)/ 20;` as `sum` is positive.